# Duda función "predict" en R

Tags: r

Leyendo un trabajo, me encontré la siguiente línea de código:

`mco <- predict(ridge.mod,s=0,newx=x[test,],exact=T)`

El `ridge.mod` proviene de aplicar la función `glmnet` a unos datos determinados, realizando una regresión con penalización.

El problema viene en la siguiente parte, entre los términos `s=0` y `exact = T`. Según he leído, si `exact=T`, los valores de penalización `s` se "unen" , entonces, cómo puede en la parte anterior darle un valor a `s`?

A mayores he probado a correr el código tal cual está escrito en el trabajo y me da el siguiente error:

"Error: used coef.glmnet() or predict.glmnet() with `exact=TRUE` so must in addition supply original argument(s)  x and y  in order to safely rerun glmnet"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien, según la documentación:

> **exact**  This argument is relevant only when predictions are made at
>   values of s (lambda) different from those used in the fitting of the
>   original model. If exact=FALSE (default), then the predict function
>   uses linear interpolation to make predictions for values of s (lambda)
>   that do not coincide with those used in the fitting algorithm. While
>   this is often a good approximation, it can sometimes be a bit coarse.
>   With exact=TRUE, these different values of s are merged (and sorted)
>   with object$lambda, and the model is refit before predictions are
>   made. In this case, **it is required to supply the original data x= and
>   y= as additional named arguments to predict() or coef()**. The workhorse
>   predict.glmnet() needs to update the model, and so needs the data used
>   to create it. The same is true of weights, offset, penalty.factor,
>   lower.limits, upper.limits if these were used in the original call.
>   Failure to do so will result in an error.

el error te está indicando que para usar el parámetro `exact=TRUE` deberías volver a indicar los parámetros originales `x` e  `y`, es decir las variables independientes y el vector de los valores dependientes.

Veamos este ejemplo bien sencillo:

```
library("glmnet")
x=matrix(rnorm(100*20),100,20)
y=rnorm(100)
test.x=matrix(rnorm(1),1,20)
model=glmnet(x,y)
```

A la hora de correr `predict()` puedes por ejemplo ver la respuesta sobre dos valores de `lambda` distintos `s=c(0.01,0.02)`:

```
predict(model,newx=test.x,s=c(0.01,0.02))

              1          2
[1,] -0.1850552 -0.2124509
```

En este ejemplo, el parámetro `exact` vale `FALSE` lo que significa que para el calculo con los distintos `lambdas` se hace una aproximación, bastante precisa pero aproximación al fin. Si quisieras un calculo más exacto, mediante `exact=TRUE` es necesario indicarle los datos iniciales ya que se debe reajustar el modelo:

```
predict(model,newx=test.x,x=x, y=y,s=c(0.01,0.02),exact = TRUE)
              1          2
[1,] -0.1850437 -0.2124528
```